# Multiple condition in single IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to add multiple condition in single IF statement in SQL.

I am not good in SQL & referred some example, all are showing only one condition in IF.

Here is my procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddApplicationUser]    
(  
@TenantId BIGINT,  
@UserType TINYINT,
@UserName  NVARCHAR(100),  
@Password NVARCHAR(100)  
)  

AS    

BEGIN   

IF ((@TenantId IS NULL)  AND (@UserType=0 OR @UserType=1) )
  RAISERROR('The value for @TenantID should not be null', 15, 1) -- with log
```

**Is this correct syntax in SQL for multiconditions in IF?**

Comment: It's valid but you would have know immediatly if you just tried it?!

Comment: I'm an Oracle guy, but this should work for SQL Server also, I use CASE and it works just like IF statements. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers i accept my mistake. I was changing a big procedure and i was worried to do this change wit out knowing the IF syntax. I searched examples, but not helped much. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 14):

Yes that is valid syntax but it may well not do what you want.

Execution will continue after your `RAISERROR` except if you add a `RETURN`. So you will need to add a block with `BEGIN ... END` to hold the two statements.

Also I'm not sure why you plumped for severity 15. That [usually indicates a syntax error](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#severitylevels).

Finally I'd simplify the conditions using `IN`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddApplicationUser] (@TenantId BIGINT,
                                            @UserType TINYINT,
                                            @UserName NVARCHAR(100),
                                            @Password NVARCHAR(100))
AS
  BEGIN
      IF ( @TenantId IS NULL
           AND @UserType IN ( 0, 1 ) )
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('The value for @TenantID should not be null',15,1);

            RETURN;
        END
  END
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is, there have to be boolean expresion after IF. Here you have a direct [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182717.aspx). I hope it helps. GL!

Comment: Your direct link also says only one condition example IF cost <= compareprice. do i need to go with nested loops ?

Comment: For exemple (cost <= compareprice AND cost <= 2) is also a valid boolean expresion.